# Which data type appropriated in mySQL for 2018-07-04 14:46:59.962000 (from python script)?

Tags: python, mysql

The value is 2018-07-04 14:46:59.962000 and I want to insert it in a column I have tried the date & datetime format, the data type originally comes from python using the below script (target_date_time_ms being in ms from epoch):

```
target_date_time_ms = (k.lastRestRequestTimestamp) 
base_datetime = datetime.datetime( 1970, 1, 1 )
delta = datetime.timedelta( 0, 0, 0, target_date_time_ms )
target_date = base_datetime + delta
```

I get this error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:50:34.943000)' at line 1")
```

Comment: What is your query string?

Comment: cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test1 (bid, q_bid, ask, q_ask, gmt) VALUES ({},{},{},{},{})""".format(bid, best_bid_quantity, ask, best_ask_quantity, target_date))

Comment: Please edit it into your original question. You also 1) shouldn't be using string formatting and 2) most of the variables in `bid, best_bid_quantity, ask, best_ask_quantity, target_date` are not defined in your code.